# EF 6 RemoveRange not working with List<entity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an entity (`MyEntity`) with a PK that is the FK of another entity. `MyEntity` has a `DateTime` (timestamp) property. I want to remove from my database all entries older then a given time (including from `MyEntity` table and entries from other tables linked with FK).

I am trying to do this with the following code, but it seems that `RemoveRange` does nothing (even though the `entities List` is successfully populated). When I check in SSMS, I still have the same number of rows in my tables before and after running the code.

What am I missing ?

```
        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dateLimit = dateNow.AddMinutes(-1);

        List<MyEntity> entities = null;

        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            entities = context.MyEntity.Where(x => x.Timestamp < dateLimit).ToList();
            context.MyEntity.RemoveRange(entities);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Are you checking the same database and also the same table? `RemoveRange` should work just fine with the code given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the list being outside of the `using` statement might be causing you issues. Try the following and see if it works for you.

```
    DateTime dateLimit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);

    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        var entities = context.MyEntity.Where(x => x.Timestamp < dateLimit);
        context.MyEntity.RemoveRange(entities);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```